# htaccess rewrite remove filename

Tags: .htaccess

How can I change url in this way using htaccess?

1. http://www.domain.com/index.html?page=home
2. http://www.domain.com/indexf6f2.html?page=blog

To

1. http://www.domain.com/?page=home
2. http://www.domain.com/?page=blog

Comment: How do you know `/?page=blog` should go to `/indexf6f2.html` and `/?page=home` should go to `/index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to generate your own `.htaccess` file based on your rules using this site http://cooletips.de/htaccess/ .

Regards, Hiawatha

Answer (score 0):

I am not giving exact solution. Just utilize the followings, then you will be able to solve other URL rewriting using .htaccess

Take help from the following URL

- http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Other important regarding rewriting through .htaccess

- http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php
- [RewriteRule to rename URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698935/rewriterule-to-rename-url)

For a nice basic

- http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html